# Dynamically adding divs in php list

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a list that is created by the code below:

```
$facilities_bid = get_the_term_list( 
                  $post->ID, 
                  'room_facilities', 
                  '<ul class="fac-styles">
                    <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">', '</i>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">', '</i>
                    </li>
                   </ul>' );
echo strip_tags($facilities_bid, '<ul><li><i>');
```

The HTML output is:

```
 <ul class="fac-styles">
  <li><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">Air Conditioning</i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">Coffee machine</i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">Flat-screen TV</i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">Free WiFi</i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">Hairdryer</i></li
  <li><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">Telephone</i></li>
  </ul>
```

I want the list to be such that, the php automatically created nested divs after after every three items to be:

```
  <div class="one">
  <ul class="fac-styles">
  <li><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">Air Conditioning</i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">Coffee machine</i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">Flat-screen TV</i></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="one">
  <ul class="fac-styles">
  <li><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">Free WiFi</i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">Hairdryer</i></li
  <li><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">Telephone</i></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: inserting a div there would be invalid html.

Comment: I have added the question to show the correct html markup

Comment: realistically you could lay it out with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tested this and I've never played with "get_the_term_list" but would this work?

```
$list = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'room_facilities', null, '|', null );
foreach( array_chunk( explode( '|', $list ), 3 ) as $outer )
{
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach( $outer as $inner )
  {
    echo '<li>' . $inner . '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Great, I really like using array chunk for this, it makes it really clear whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try using small counter inside the code, which considers where to put nested div. f.e.

```
$gtnum=0;
    foreach() {    
    $gtnum++;
    if ($gtnum==0) $divstart='<div>'; else $divstart='';
    if ($gtnum==3) {$gtnum=0; $divend='</div>';} else $divend='';
    $facilities_bid = get_the_term_list( 
                          $post->ID, 
                          'room_facilities', 
                          $divstart.'<ul class="fac-styles">
                            <li>
                            <i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">', '</i>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true">', '</i>
                            </li>
                           </ul>'.$divend );
        echo strip_tags($facilities_bid, '<ul><li><i><div>');
    }
```